# Read value from function returning pointer

Tags: c

I am developing a code in which I need to read the value of function which returns value in pointer.

below is the function whose value needs to be read (*ip)

```
int16_t getLastValueFromADC()
{
    volatile uint16_t *ip;

    ip  = GET_FPGA_REGISTER_ADDRESS(REG_CURRENT_ADC_SAMPLE_R);

#ifdef _JSB_BEHAVIOUR_0_65536
    if (tighteningDirectionCCW)
    {
        tempValue = (int16_t)(*ip);
        tempValue = (OFFSET_BB2AD - tempValue);
    }
    else
    {
        tempValue = ((*ip) + OFFSET_BB2AD);
    }
    return ((uint16_t)tempValue);
#endif
    return *ip;
}
```

I am reading the value using below code:

```
int16_t vref2v5 = getLastValueFromADC();             
printf("VREF2V5 Status for Torque signal:  %d\n",vref2v5);
```

not getting expected values it is showing some negative value number.

Please suggest

Thanks & Regards

Comment: `some negative value number` - change `int16_t` into `uint16_t` ?

Comment: I think using int16_t instead of uint16_t is you problem: the strongest bit is interpreted as a minus and not as 2^15

Comment: After changing to `uint16_t` also change printf specifier to `"%u\n"` (or `"%" PRIu16 "\n"` with the inclusion of `<inttypes.h>`)

Comment: In many cases, the value isn't stored as a plain number, but with a certain encoding, which you have to decode first. Consult the specifications of the FPGA and the hardware design it runs.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of the function is a 16 bit integer,

```
int16_t getLastValueFromADC();
```

However the variable used to represent the result to be returned by the function is an unsigned integer.

```
volatile uint16_t *ip;
```

Unsigned integers are meant to be parsed by the compiler in such a way that there value is always positive. This is not the case with regular(signed) integers, in which case the MSB(most significant bit; leftmost bit) determines whether the value should be treated as postive(0) or negative(1).